# bootstrap alert box is too big in height when link is in it

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to put links in bootstrap alert box but when I do the box is too big in height? When I change the css height the text and the link is well below it? What am I doing wrong? Thankyou

The code is

```
<div id = "mystuff" margin-top: 15px" class="alert alert-info">
<span id="mystuff1"><button id = "button1" type = "button" class = "btn btn-link">click here</button></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not leave much detail of what you are trying to achieve, but based on what you are doing as you add elements inside the outer container it grows too tall?

This is happening because the top container has the `.alert` class. And this class has padding: 15px;

If you remove that padding you should see what I think you want.

Try:

```
<div id="mystuff" style="margin-top: 15px; padding: 0;" class="alert alert-info">
  <span id="mystuff1">
    <button id="button1" type="button" class="btn btn-link">click here</button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot test it right now, but I think you have to change the mystuff1 from span to div or p element.

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code contains an error:

```
<div id = "mystuff" margin-top: 15px" class="alert alert-info">
```

That should be

```
<div id = "mystuff" style="margin-top: 15px" class="alert alert-info">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet.

```
<div id="mystuff" style="margin-top: 15px; padding: 0;" class="alert alert-info">
        <span id="mystuff1">
            <button id="button1" type="button" class="btn btn-link">click here</button>
        </span>
    </div>
```

You also find  the detail of alert in below link:
[bootstrap alert details](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts)